# I get Type Mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm have data sheet that contains year in A column, month in B column, day in C column and total count in d

I'm trying to create function that sums month today stats from d column

```
    Function countMessagesbyDate(xYear As Integer, xMonth As Integer, xDay As Integer) As Integer

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim tMessages As Integer
    Dim rowYear As Range
    Dim rowMonth As Range
    Dim rowDay As Range
    Dim rowMessages As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsJData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("daily_report")
    Set rowYear = wsData.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rowMonth = wsData.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rowDay = wsData.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Rows
    Set rowMessages = wsData.Range("D1:").End(xlDown).Rows

    tMessages = 0
    i = 0

    For Each rCell In rowYear
        i = i + 1
        If rCell.Value = xYear And rowMonth.Offset(i) = xMonth And rowDay.Offset(i) < Day(Today) Then
            tMessages = tMessages + rowMessages.Offset(i).Value
        End If
    Next rCell

    countMessagesbyDate = tMessages

    End Function
```

I get type missmatch when trying to set ranges. Can you please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post the error please

Comment: If you use xlDown, I think you get many row. Should it be xlRight? Or better somethink like wsData.Rows(1)?

Comment: which line please?  Put `Option Explicit` at top of module.  It helps.

Answer (score 2):

You stated: -

> I get type missmatch when trying to set ranges

You have declared `rowYear` as a range (`Dim rowYear As Range`) but then supplied a number to it not a range, hence the mismatch. `Set rowYear = wsData.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row` will supply the row number not the range.

To fix this either change the declaration: -

```
Dim rowYear As Long
```

or change the setting of the variable: -

```
Set rowYear = wsData.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Range
```

Comment: In the latter case you can omit "Range"

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error, but it returned value "0" for tMessages

Comment: @daba Glad I could answer it. Your comment is a different question for you to ask as you will need to show us your new code and give more description on the new issue.

Answer (score 1):

You declare this variable:

`Dim wsData As Worksheet`

but then you set this variable:

`Set wsJData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("daily_report")`

Then you try to call the variable you `Dim`'d, but the problem is that it is empty.

So if you change `wsJData` to `wsData`, your code will probably work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple Countifs() will do it for you instead of your UDF.

If you are very keen in using UDF why dont you use Countifs() in your UDF instead of looping through each cells.